# Custom Loop with certain number of one category

Tags: categories, loop

I have a custom loop that shows 120 posts in total on a certain page. The posts are from several categories. That works perfectly. But I need to change it.

I need:

- 120 posts only of the category 2
- all posts of other cats can be displayed without any limitation.   Is this possible?

My loop goes like this:

```
            global $post;
            $tmp_post = $post;
            $args = array( 
            'numberposts' => '120',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'DESC',
            'cat' => array(1,2,7,8,9,27, 30, 31),
            'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => array( 'post-format-aside','post-format-video' ),
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                        ),
                    )        
 );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
            foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); 
        ?>
```

Thanks

[EDIT] I updated the question in order to make it more clear. [/EDIT]

Comment: yes, just ask for 2, instead o 1,2,7,8,9,27,30, and 31. Also note that the `NOT IN` `tax_query` is ultra expensive and very slow/heavy on the database

Comment: And what, if I need to ask for 1, 2, 7, 8, 9... (?)  That is the given code, I cannot change it as I want.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to make changes you have to change the code. Why can't you change the code?

Comment: Off course I have to change the code. ;) But the solution to kick out some categories is not a real solution. I want the code as it is, but the output of cat 2 (and only cat 2!) should be stopped after a max of 120 posts.

Comment: I see, that's not what your question asked, can you edit your question to make that clearer? Right now what your question says and what you want, are not the same

Answer (score 0):

If you only want posts from the category with ID 2, that's easy, only ask for category 2:

```php
'cat' => array( 2 ),
```

Comment: No, I want it as it is. but instead of a maximum of 120 in total I want a maximum of 120 of cat 2. The other cats should be without a maximum, so all posts should be shown.

Comment: That's not what your question asks, you should update your question to reflect what you actually want

Comment: I updated the question now. Hope it is more clear now.